# Force TensorRT to run on CPU, or convert trt model back to onnx?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, gpu, tensorrt

I realize this is not the intended usage of TensorRT, but I am a bit stuck so maybe there are some ideas out there.  Currently I have been provided some neural network models as TensorRT serialized engines, so-called .trt files.  These are basically models compiled and optimized from PyTorch to run on a specific GPU.

Now, this works fine since I do have a compatible GPU for development, however, for setting up CI/CD, I am having some trouble because the cloud servers on which it will be running *for testing purposes only* do *not* have adequate GPUs for this CUDA-compiled "engine".

So, I would like to force these models to run on CPU, or otherwise find some other way to make them run.  On CPU would be just fine, because I just need to run handful of inferences to check the output, it is fine if it's slow.  Again, I know this is not the intended usage of TensorRT, but I need some output from the models for integration testing.

**Alternative approach**

The other idea I had was maybe to convert the .trt files back to .onnx or another format that I could load into another runtime engine, or just into PyTorch or TensorFlow, but I cannot find any TensorRT tools that load an engine and write a model file.  Presumably because it is "compiled" and no longer convertible; yet, the model parameters must be in there, so does anyone know how to do such a thing?

Comment: I don't think running TensorRT on CPU is possible. Here is an answer from [nvidia's developer forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/tensorrt-int8-with-cpu-only/68026)

Comment: darn, looks like you're right.  makes testing difficult!  thanks for the pointer to the forum post, very helpful to have something to refer to.

Comment: Yeah I also had this issue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how TensorRT is meant to be used. An answer to the question in TensorRT forums [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/can-we-execute-tensorrt-models-on-cpu/158030).

However, you might be interested in [this](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/issues/992) answer. It points out [Triton](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server). [Here](https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/blob/main/docs/getting_started/quickstart.md#run-on-cpu-only-system) is a guide on that. It runs on Docker which is probably suitable for your CI system.

Another solution would be to get a device that has a Nvidia GPU running in your CI but I understand that you're trying to avoid this solution.

> The other idea I had was maybe to convert the .trt files back to .onnx or another format that I could load into another runtime engine, or just into PyTorch or TensorFlow, but I cannot find any TensorRT tools that load an engine and write a model file.

This is not possible. See my other answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75688465/convert-a-tensor-rt-engine-file-back-to-source-onnx-file-or-pytorch-model-wight/75760530#75760530).